# how to perform multiple action in html form using php?

Tags: php, javascript, action

```
$i=0;
echo '<html><body>';
echo '<form name="Form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="'."https://xxx/".$uid[$i]."/send".'" method="POST">';
echo '<input name="message" type="text" value=""><br/><br/>';
echo '<input type="submit" value="SEND" /><br/>';
echo '</form>';
echo '</body></html>';
```

uid array has 500 elements so 500 actions should be performed.

I want to perform such multiple actions. I hope u got it by my code.
Please tell how to do this or please give some alternative.

Comment: While this seems like an absurd idea, if you want to POST to 500 URLs at one time, you'll need AJAX.

Comment: seems like spam to me :p

Comment: Are you wanting a different message to be submitted for each user id? Or are you trying to send the same message to all user ids?

Comment: i wanna send same message to all.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, what I would do in this instance is just have the form post to 1 php page, and on that php page perform all the actions you want to accomplish.  I have never heard of a form posting to multiple locations and don't think it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript function to provide action url and submit. Keep form target = "_parent" but this seem to be spam only.

Comment: Its not spam.i have to msg to all members how have paid, msg will be sent to them only.....and that list will be dynamic genrated

Comment: Use target as following not in javascript. echo '<form name="Form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="'."https://xxx/".$uid[$i]."/send".'" method="POST" target="_blank">';

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to do what I think you're trying to do, and that's messaging all users on your website the same message, then you're doing it wrong.

Implement some sort of announcement module, that all users can see in their inbox. If you don't want to message to ALL users, but just a smaller group, implement groups in your website.

It's not possible for an HTML form to submit to more than one location.

Comment: its not my site.its kind of app to site